# Eeeeek! MSO JS is all borked!

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, javascript

I just noticed that clicking a JS-like link on MSO (like to show more hot network questions) just bumps me to the top of the page and doesn't do anything else.

Also, adding a comment or any other JS-related feature (i.e. inline editing, 10k inline comment editing) is borked.

Comment: [status-completed]

Comment: I just had it, and now it seems to be fixed :-D

Comment: Wow, that was fast!

Comment: Do comment upvotes work now?

Comment: Fixed, very nice.

Comment: Yes. Everyone test on this comment!

Comment: Fixed for me too

Comment: @JoshC I think its bugged, you gained too many too fast

Comment: +1 for the Muppet reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, that was my bad.  Time to back go spin the wheel of blame to make sure we choose an appropriate victim.  I should have shelved a change and instead pushed the go live button.

Comment: Damn programmers

Comment: Next time ask your manager first before you push ANY button, please.

Comment: Feature request:  an "are you sure" button

Comment: Vindicated - somebody pulled out the JS compilation safety net which is supposed to throw errors if one of us decides to do something stupid and jump from our 10,000 foot platform.  And yes, I hit the ground - HARD.

Answer (score 11):

Voting is broken: the one valid use case ever for a "me, too" answer?

Sign the petition below the line if you're having the same p0rblem. You will all be expected to upvote the question when things are fixed.

---

- Undo
- JoshC
- bfavaretto & sergio - This is also happening on Stack Overflow em Português, and its meta. (and we are overwriting each other's edits here)
- MattDMo
- [image: Martijn Pieters]

Wheeee! Edit warz!

Comment: I was wondering how many clobbered edits would result. That was funny for a minute or two.

Comment: Looks like you guys had some fun! :)

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be happening for the following buttons

- Share
- Flag
- Any of the formatting posts at the top of the posts page
- Vote buttons
- Flag and close buttons
- View Vote counts doesn't take me to the top of the page, but it doesn't show vote counts either
- More hot questons

Yaaay it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

That is fantastic, it is borked. And I had to get through robot anti-verification to post this.

When I click on anything that requires JS, it seems to be trying to load a URL that happens to be one of my bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Favoriting doesn't work either.

Comment: Except that it's fixed now.

Comment: Yep, glad I can vote now also, maybe it's all fixed.